# Set in app billing item as free

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I have a question about in app billing Android.

I have a list of items and it's price, some items in my list are free and other is have price.
So my question is : How to set item's price at $0.00 or make item free?

I searched and found this link : https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/1153485?hl=en&ref_topic=15867.
This link says that I can't set price at $0.00 :(.

Here is sample about my item list:

Product 1   --- $1.00
Product 2   --- $0.00
Product 3   --- $10.0

Thanks !

Comment: If something is free, why does it need to be an in-app purchase in the first place?

Comment: Because some items are free but other is not free

Comment: Exactly... shouldn't the free items just be included in the app in the first place? Since this seems to be a question about Android policies, it might be better suited elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The minimum price for in-app purchases is $0.99 (or roughly the equivalent in other currencies).